# Use a field alias as the key of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, sql, google-bigquery

How do I use a field alias as the key of a javascript object?

```
const countries = {
    'united states of america': 'US',
    'india': 'IN',
    'china': 'CN'
}
const query = `SELECT country AS ctry, IF(true, '${countries[ctry]}', 'p') AS c FROM ${table}`
```

This obviously returns `ctry is not defined` error as `ctry` is considered a javascript variable. Is there a way to make this query return values of keys in the `countries` object when the key is retrieved from database?

Comment: You need to write a proper query with `CASE` statements.

Comment: @VLAZ will I be able to access ${countries[ctry]} in `CASE` statements? I don't want to give cases for all countries since there will be hundereds of them. I'm planning to store it in a json file.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL CASE](https://sql.sh/cours/case)

And this done:

```js
const countries = {
    'united states of america': 'US',
    'india': 'IN',
    'china': 'CN'
}
const query = `SELECT country AS ctry, CASE WHEN ctry='united states of america' THEN 'US' as c WHEN ctry='india' THEN 'IN' as c WHEN ctry='china' THEN 'CN' as c ELSE 'no country find' as c END FROM ${table}`
```

Comment: the problem with this is there will be hundereds of of cases for all countries.. I'm looking to store it in a json file and access it dynamically. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in json object you need to use a for:

```js
const countries = {
    'united states of america': 'US',
    'india': 'IN',
    'china': 'CN'
}
const query = `SELECT country AS ctry FROM ${table}`

//Execute here your request

let c = [];

for (let i = 0; i < query.length; i ++) {
  c.push(query[i]['country'])
}

for (let j = 0; j < c.length; j ++) {
  c[j] = countrie[c[j]]
}

console.log(c)
```

I can't do more with your information.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `countries` object into an array using `Object.entries` then `.map` them to output `WHEN '${i[0]}' THEN '${i[1]}'`. This will give you the `WHEN` parts for each country. Just append this string into your `query` (`CASE country \n${caseStr}\nEND`) then you'll have the full CASE Statement built for you.

```js
const table = 'test';
const countries = {
  'united states of america': 'US',
  'india': 'IN',
  'china': 'CN'
};
const caseStr = Object.entries(countries).map(i => `WHEN '${i[0]}' THEN '${i[1]}'`).join('\n');

const query = `SELECT country AS ctry \n, CASE country \n${caseStr}\nEND AS c FROM ${table}`
console.log(query);
```

Why store it in JSON though? It looks like you can access the DB anyway, why not store the countries in a table to which you can `JOIN` your query to?